# Add content above the product short description on the product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for a way to insert a custom content between the product title and its short description on the product page in WooCommerce. So far I was only able to add a custom content at the beginning of the short description with the following code:

```
function insert_content( $post_excerpt )  {
      $content = 'My custom content';
       return $content.'<br>'.$post_excerpt; } 
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'insert_content', 10, 1);
```

However, I need this content to be between the product title and the short description title, not below this last one. I guess I am using the wrong hook but the few others I've tried don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the [`content-single-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8d83f2dcc5b1414774c26a22af2321e972f4ff9a/templates/content-single-product.php#L66) template. You will see that the title and the short description are both attached to the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook with different priorities. If you want to insert content between them, add it to that hook with a priority that is in between the two values. The title is on 5 and the excerpt is on 20 so 15 would be between the two, but still after the price and the ratings.

```
function so_43922864_add_content(){
    echo 'TACOS!';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'so_43922864_add_content', 15 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much Helga for both the answer and the explanation! This works perfectly :)

Comment: How can I make the custom content dynamic, so that I can have different content on all products

Comment: @VivekNathR you can access the global product object. `global $product` inside the function. Then you can use that to set up some conditional logic.